# Java error "not a statement" for the following program.but if i change the return type void to int and write return stck[tos--]; works fine

Tags: java

```
class stack
{
    private int stck[]=new int[10];
    private int tos;
    stack()
    {
        tos=-1;
    }
    void push(int item)
    {
        if(tos==9)
        {
            System.out.println("stack is full");
        }
        else
        {
            stck[++tos]=item;
        }
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if(tos<0)
        {
             System.out.println("stack is empty");
             //return 0;
        }
        else
        {
             //return 
             stck[tos--];
        }
    } 
}

class testStack
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        stack s1=new stack();
        stack s2=new stack();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            s1.push(i);
        }
        for(i=10;i<20;i++)
        {
            s2.push(i);
        }       
    }
}
```

why should I return a value for pop function?
I can't use return type of void for pop function. It always asks me to return a value. It shows 'not a statement' for pop() if the method return type is void.

Comment: Please format your code properly...

Comment: stck[tos--] just decrements the index. That is the reason it is not a statement. Use stck[tos--] = 0 instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler is not lying: `stck[tos--]` is not a statement, it’s an expression. While many languages allow using expressions as complete statements, Java does not. In this case, replace it with `tos--` (which is both an expression and a statement) and you’re good.